# GCM service doensn't work on certain devices

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Our Android app is intended to receive GCM push notifications. As for implementation I entierly used provided example: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html without any modifications.

I have two devices to test on:

- My cellphone: Android 4.4.4, 1 SIM, Google Play and other Google stuff,
- A tablet of unknown chineese manufacturer: Android 4.4, no SIM but it's possible, Google Play Services only as described in manual of GCM.

An application will be diffused only with these tablets.

The problem is that my cellphone receives push messages but tablet does not although:

- devices are registered successfully,
- sending from server to google GCM servers passes without errors (in single query for both or in separates). Response is always OK.

I just wonder what is relevant for GCM service to deliver a notification (components, google apps, SIM, parameters, settings).

Please help.

Comment: what is the vendor of your tablet, xiaomi, samsung or other? Try update google play service via application manager or Google Play. Try to hard reset your tablet. Also to be sure that you enabled specific settings like a "Enable push notification" or something else, some chineese devices had these settings.

Comment: Manufacturer is BAOXUE. Actually there is option "Notifications" is settings, but it's turned on. Tablet was shipped without google play apps.

Comment: WOW it works at my place! I changed nothing but when I just tested at my place the gcm-notifications was delivered... What happened? Bug? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Note: If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your Android devices to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept outgoing connections to all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169.